# Variable contents not being persistent

Tags: java, class, variables, methods

I'm having a bit of trouble with trying to save user input into a variable, and then later accessing the contents of that variable. Basically, the user enters details about a song which are then saved in the next available song slot (4 slots total). But when I check to see if a slot is empty or filled, it's always empty as the last song details havn't saved.

Code:

SongDatabase class:

```
if (song1.getFileSize() == 0) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song1.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song1.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song1.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song1.setDuration(console.nextInt());
}

else if (song2.getFileSize() == 0) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song2.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song2.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song2.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song2.setDuration(console.nextInt());
}

else if (song3.getFileSize() == 0) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song3.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song3.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song3.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song3.setDuration(console.nextInt());
}

else if (song4.getFileSize() == 0) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song4.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song4.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song4.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song4.setDuration(console.nextInt());
}

else {
    System.out.println("The database is currently full. Please delete a song before adding a new one.");
}
```

Song class:

```
public void setName(String inputName) {
    name = inputName;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setArtist(String inputArtist) {
    artist = inputArtist;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return artist;
}

public void setFileSize(int inputFileSize) {
    fileSize = inputFileSize;
}

public int getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}

public void setDuration(int inputDuration) {
    duration = inputDuration;
}

public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}
```

Do I need to add another parameter in the get/set methods or am I doing something completely wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have left out the declarations of the fields, etcetera, and the code that (supposedly) shows that the "slots" are "completely empty".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use constructor

```
song1 = new song("Name of song:","Artist:","File size (MB):","Duration (seconds):")
```

same thing for the other objects

Then, you need to add a method inside your song class

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
        if (this.name == null && this.artist == null && this.fileSize == null && this.duration == null ) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```